# When does the item drop limit reset?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

For TF2 the "drop reset" is claimed to be Thursday at GMT 00:00.  Assuming that they are both Valve/Source games it could be the same time for drop reset - but I don't know if this is the case.

Can anyone confirm that it is the same, or if not, what time does the reset happen for CS:GO?

Comment: http://josh3d.com/csgo/ - can't vouch for it, but I did receive a drop around Wednesday or Thursday this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact time when the drop cap reset is not known. The only thing we know is that it is resets weekly.

> Q: How do I earn decorated weapons by playing the game?
>
> A: Weapon
> drops are awarded for play time over the course of a week. As your
> play time increases, the drop rate will slow down. **The drop rate will**
> **reset when the week rolls over**.

<sub>from the [Arms Deal Update FAQ](http://blog.counter-strike.net/armsdeal/faq.php)</sub>

There is a [website](http://josh3d.com/csgo/) that shows a timer of the cs:go cap reset. I am not sure if that is accurate because I searched for the exact time using Google an no one knows it. Also, other players said that they didn't get any drops after the timer ran out.

Someone on HLTV wrote:

> its all depends on the first time u get ur first drop ever

<sub>from [HLTV Forum](http://www.hltv.org/forum/493365-the-truth-about-csgo-drop-reset-timers)</sub>

It could be true but it is not very trustworthy...

We do not know the exact time when the cap is reset.

My **guess** is that the week starts with the Arms Deal Updated. That means the first day of the drop cap week is Tuesday (the updated was released on 13. AUG 2013). I did not verify that but it would fit together with my drop rate.

Comment: Well answered.  Will award if no-one can come forward with anything firm.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get two drops every monday, and i see that alot of people get drops in my games on monday. So, i think it resets on monday, or its player based.

Answer (score -2):

yes it is Tuesday same as tf2 i think
cause now  the rank drops show up every morning on Tuesday

Comment: Would you mind providing a source for this?